# using sessions to add an edit button for the right user

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, mongoose

Lets say I have a lot of reviews on a web page. and I have a `req.session.shortId = f43f1`. I'm new to sessions but I think that each person that goes to the page will have their own `req.session.shortId`. (I have this in my schema `shortId : {type : String, unique : true, default : shortId.generate},` )

some reviews are made by one person and I want to have those reviews have an edit button. only the person that has the session should be able to see the edit button. I have on the page something like this `<div class = "f43f1">Review</div>` , `<div class = "f43aa">Review</div>`. I only want `f43f1` to have the button because that is the value of `req.session.shortId`. I was thinking of doing something like this on the server.

```
if(req.session.shortId == req.body.shortId){

I really don't know what to do

how would I tell the user's div that he can edit the button

I do stuff like this

res.render("index", {user : user, comp, comp, how do I send out tell the specific div to put the edit button })

}
```

Truthfully I don't even want the shortId in the div because of security concers. I don't know how developers handle this type of situation

Comment: How are you handling the view here?  Pure HTML/CSS/JS or templating with node or something else?  Makes a lot of difference in being able to answer.

Comment: I use ejs template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you would have that shortId stored with your review in the database.  Which should make it easy enough to do something like this in your node app:

`res.render('index', {shortId: req.session.shortId, review: review});`

Then on your ejs template you should be able to conditionally display the button similar to something like this:

```
<% if (shortId === review.shortId) { %>
  <button type="submit">Edit</button>
<% } %>
```

Sorry if the syntax is a little off here, it's been a while since I've worked with EJS.